# Are Github-Flavored Markdown task lists used in the real world?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

In a [2013 blog post](https://github.com/blog/1375-task-lists-in-gfm-issues-pulls-comments) Github introduced task lists for Github-Flavored Markdown. I am looking for examples of this feature being used in the wild. Can you point me to any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from Google repository on Github

[Pull request checkmarks](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/pull/52)